# django web app accessed by multiple users

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to implement a web based quiz application

I'm currently using django and html / JavaScript – only running on localhost so far
(python manage.py runserver)

For one single user, the quiz is working fine, but multiple users are not able to play individually atm.

How do i handle concurrent access to the quiz? I considered using the request.session data structure but storing the complete quiz in there somehow feels wrong. And different users might play a totally different set of questions …

Somehow I'd like to start a new thread each time a user access the webpage and starts the quiz (like I'd do it in some offline application), but im not sure if this is the right approach for web dev.

I also read that this is maybe done by the real webserver, e.g. apache? Should I try to put the django app on apache?

Also considered docker and started a small tutorial this morning.

I can post some code ofc, or provide more implementation details if necessary but at the moment I need to get a basic understanding of web development best practices ;-)

Scenario:

User A starts quiz and answers the first 5 questions.

User B starts quiz - it will start at question 6.
--> User B should start at question 1.

How can i isolate User A from User B?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.